# how to replace a fragment in kotlin from a onclicklistener inside a recyclerview

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

How can I replace the fragment when i click on an item inside a recyclerView

I've tried inside onClickListener of adapter

```java
    childFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.framefragment2, Fragment2())
                .commit()
```

with no succes it returns me

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0137 (com.test.justaapp:id/framefragment1) for fragment Fragmetnone{1ebd5fc #0 id=0x7f0a0137}
```

Here is mi xml of 1st fragment already inflated

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/framefragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and the second frame layout

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C0C0C0">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framefragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

I've been searching for hours and can't get it to work, any ideas? maybe I'm mimssing something very simple, any help would be apreciated Greets.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an interface on your ViewHolder, then you pass an implementation of this interface to your adapter from your activity. In your adapter your pass the implementation when you create the CustomViewHolder instance (create method).

In your activity/fragment:

```
private val adapter = YourAdapter(object: CustomViewHolder.Listener {
    fun onClick() {
        // change the fragment here with the fragment manager of your activity/fragment.
    }
})
```

In your adapter:

```
class YourAdapter(private val listener: CustomViewHolder.Listener): RecyclerView.Adapter {

    ...

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return CustomViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_layout, parent, false), 
            listener
        )
    }
}
```

ViewHolder implementation:

```
class CustomViewHolder(view: View, private val listener: Listener): ViewHolder(view) {

    ...    

    interface Listener {
        fun onClick()
    }

    fun onCreate(parent: View, listener: Listener): CustomViewHolder {
        // inflate the view and return an instance of CustomViewHolder
    }

    fun onBind() {
        button.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onClick()
        }
    }    
}
```

I didn't test this code but the logic is here. You just need to adapt it to your project.